# How do i use User input in a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, input

I have an assignment where I'm asked to to repeat a list but with different `"items"` (I guess you would call it that).

the only problem that I seem to have is figuring out how to change the `list` with  user `input` and how to use something like a `counter`

I'm supposed to change:
`random_things=['food', 'room', 'drink', 'pet']`

into:
`random_things=['apple', 'bedroom', 'apple juice', 'dog']`

But I have to do this `7` times so I need to be able to keep the lists separate like `random_things[1]`, `random things[2]`, `etc`.

I'm in grade 11 so please try and keep it as simple as you possibly can as this is my first year coding

Answer (score 0):

Not fully sure what the message to the user should be what you want is  for range loop and to loop over he random_things words:

```
random_things=['food', 'room', 'drink', 'pet']
# store all the lists of input
output = []

# loop 7 times
for _ in range(7):
    # new list for each set of input
    temp = []
    # for each word in random_things
    for word in random_things:
       # ask user to input a related word/phrase
        temp.append(input("Choose something related to {}".format(word)) )
    output.append(temp)
```

Instead of the `temp` list you could use a [list comprehension](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/lists/list-comprehensions-in-python/):

```
random_things = ['food', 'room', 'drink', 'pet']
output = []
for _ in range(7):
    output.append([input("Choose something related to {}".format(word)) for word in random_things])
```

Which could be combined into one single list comprehension:

```
output = [[input("Choose something related to {}".format(w)) for w in random_things]
          for _ in range(7)]
```

If you have to use a count variable, you can use while loops:

```
random_things=['food', 'room', 'drink', 'pet']
# store all the lists of input
output = []

# set count to 0
count = 0
# loop seven times
while count < 7:
    # new list for each set of input
    temp = []
    index = 0
    # loop until index is < the length of random_things
    while index < len(random_things):
       # ask user to input a related word/phrase
       # use index to access word in random_thongs
        temp.append(input("Choose something related to {}".format(random_things[index])) )
        index += 1
    output.append(temp)
    # increase count after each inner loop
    count += 1
```

lists indexes start at 0 so the first element is at index 0 not index 1.

Comment: @MiaLegaspi, first iteration will output `Choose something related to food`, second `Choose something related to room` etc..

Comment: is there a way where I can use a counter  instead of a for loop? something like random_things += 1 or is that impossible?

Comment: You can,  in place of the for loops you can use while loops.  i=1 then while i < 7 etc...

Comment: 1 last thing,, I want to print out all of these on separate lines so how would i do that? would it be `print(random_things[0])` and so on?

Comment: Use a for loop looping over the list or use the index, everything you need to achieve that is already in the answer.

Comment: guess I was vague in what I said before, because I need to be able to print out all of the different lists separately while i have different words and with them. Like "Sallys favourite things are random_things[1]." and "Johns favourite things are random_things[2]"

Comment: All the logic to achieve that is in the answer, me doing it all for you is not going to help you learn.